# Bringing voxel from ArcGIS Pro/Online to Unity

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, unity3d, voxel, augmented-reality

I'd like to bring a voxel visualization from ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS Online into Unity, and then from there add interactions from the Mixed Reality Toolkit to allow for exploration in XR.

However, I can't find a direct way to take them from ArcGIS software to Unity. The ArcGIS Maps SDK for Unity does [not](https://developers.arcgis.com/unity/layers/#data-layers) [support](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/is-it-possible-to-import-an-arcgis-pro/m-p/1305038) voxel layers. The only other idea I had was to somehow export the voxel to Blender and then export the model to Unity.

What do you suggest?